# validate user credentials with sfGuard

Tags: php, symfony1, authentication, propel, sfguard

I use symfony 1.4 with sfGuard with Propel, and considering that this is my first symfony experience, I'm still a total noob with some part of the architecture.

I was asked to create some webservices, one of this shall be taking user (email) and password and print out a json string feedback as result.

I don't have a clue about how to perform such a task with sfGuard, so if anybody has an example it'd be appreciated.

I think that the algorithm should be sha1, because in the sf_guard_user table I found rows like

```
id  username                algorithm   salt                            password                                    created_at              last_login              is_active   is_super_admin
4   myuser@myhostname.com   sha1    623de866b49c696b452e0d12b55895c8    dcbe87a60a769b9e3b5f0988141b824fa5206235    2011-12-06 02:32:43     2011-12-27 15:49:41     1           0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a dirty trick, but it works.

I can fake a login form submission and sitck to the usual login patter, which it becomes something like:

```
        $request->setParameter('signin', array(
                'username' =>$request->getParameter("username"),
                'password' =>$request->getParameter("password"),
              ));
        $form = new BeetleLoginForm();
        $form->bind($request->getParameter('signin'));
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $values = $form->getValues();
            $this->getUser()->signin($values['user'], false);
            $resp['return'] = "YES";
            $resp['message'] = "You have successfully logged in";
            return $this->renderText(json_encode($resp));

        }
```

I hope that this could help somebody stuck in the same limbo.

Comment: You don't need the request.Just use the array for the bind method.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at `sfGuardValidatorUser` class.
Basically it's something like this:

1. Check if a user with the given username exists
2. If 1. then check if it's active (is_active field)
3. If 2. then check the password using the `checkPassword` public method from the `sfGuardUser`  class (default is something like `sha1(db_salt.submitted_password) == db_password`)